# Get Unique First Names in Pandas series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
I have a the following dataframe using pandas. 

Names

Jason
Jason M
John
John S
Nate
Dave
```

I want to get the unique names. In this case, the output I am looking for is

```
Nate
Dave
```

I have the following codes but it does not print what I am looking for.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.Names.unique())
print(df)
```

Where should I fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get first names by splitting whitespace, then drop duplicates.

```
df['FirstNames'] = df['Names'].str.split().str[0]

unique = df['FirstNames'].drop_duplicates(keep=False).values.tolist()

# ['Nate', 'Dave']
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you're actually trying to do is remove duplicate first names, then you first need to isolate the first names, then use [`drop_duplicates()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to remove the duplicated rows:

```
df.Names.apply(lambda n: n.split(' ', 1)[0]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```